# UIBarButtonItem-Badge: badge won't show

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, badge

I am using [UIBarButtonItem-Badge](https://github.com/mikeMTOL/UIBarButtonItem-Badge). When created `UIBarButtonItem` in storyboard badge display fine. But when created `UIBarButtonItem` programmatically badge not displayed.

Following is my Code:

```
@property UIBarButtonItem *pendingRequestButton;
```

viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    _pendingRequestButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PendingRequestBarButtonItemImage_filled"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self  action:@selector(pendingRequestButtonAction:)];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:_pendingRequestButton animated:YES];
}
```

viewDidAppear method:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [_pendingRequestButton setBadgeValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",[[[UserDefaultsManager sharedManager] objectForKey:@"panding_requests_count"] integerValue]]];
    [_pendingRequestButton setBadgeBGColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [_pendingRequestButton setBadgeTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add the code for setBadgeValue:, setBadgeBGColor:, and setbadgeTextColor methods?

Comment: [this lib](https://github.com/mikeMTOL/UIBarButtonItem-Badge)

Comment: It would have been nice if you'd have told us from the beginning that you are using that external library. Anyway, that's a library not being updated in the last four years, and the bar button items have had a massive rethinking not too long ago, so it *might* be just a compatibility issue. May I suggest you try and look for something more fresh?

Answer (score 0):

try this in objective c

self.tabBarController?.tabBarItem.badgeColor = UIColor.red
        self.tabBarController?.tabBarItem.badgeValue = "12"

Comment: use UIBarButtonItem not tabBarItem

Answer (score 0):

I think I spot the issue, it seems you forget to add the bar button to the navigation item in viewDidLoad.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = _pendingRequestButton;
```

Comment: I add this sorry I forgot to write in question.

Comment: I think there is a problem with the library it self. I had run the demo project and I end up in the same problem. It seems to work only for the case when you init with custom view, `[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button]`

Comment: There is in fact a problem with the library. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is a compatibility issue between UIBarButtonItem-Badge and iOS 11, as stated [here](https://github.com/mikeMTOL/UIBarButtonItem-Badge/issues/37)

Comment: I am use PPBadgeView: https://github.com/jkpang/PPBadgeView but same issue.

Comment: This is a different issue, being it a totally different library. Are you using the same code?

Comment: I am create UIBarButtonItem programmatically. when create in storyboard it work.

Comment: Then, since the issue is related to another library and the code is different, please mark this question as resolved and open a new one stating that you are using that other library and showing the code you are using.